# Display the average price of a book

Tags: javascript

I need some code that implements calculating the average price of books, type of `ROMAN`. The type field can be written in any case (roman, ROMAN).

```
let books = [
  { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
  { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
  { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
  { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
  { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
  { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hohol', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
];
```

So I derived all types with this method:

```
const getType = books.map(({type}) => type.toLowerCase())
```

And further my problem is that I don't know how got access to price

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in several Method

You can loop trough the array and sum up all the prices there and then devide on its length, also you will check if the current object type equals `roman`, by using `.toLowerCase()`

if you want to return the natural number you can use `.toFixed()` method

## For Loop

```js
let books = [
    { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
    { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
    { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
    { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hoho', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
 ]
 
let TotalPrice = 0;
let romanPriceLength = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  if ((books[i].type).toLowerCase() === "roman") {
    TotalPrice += books[i].price
    romanPriceLength++
  }
}

console.log(TotalPrice / romanPriceLength)
console.log((TotalPrice / romanPriceLength).toFixed(0))
```

## forEach()

```js
let books = [
    { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
    { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
    { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
    { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hoho', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
 ]


let TotalPrice = 0;
let romanPriceLength = 0;

 books.forEach(book => {
  if((book.type).toLowerCase() === "roman"){
    TotalPrice += book.price
    romanPriceLength ++
  }
 })
 
 console.log(TotalPrice / romanPriceLength)
 console.log((TotalPrice / romanPriceLength ).toFixed(0))
```

## for ... of

```js
let books = [
    { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
    { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
    { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
    { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hoho', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
 ]

let romanPriceLength = 0;
let TotalPrice = 0;

for(let book of books){
  if(book.type.toLowerCase() === "roman"){
    TotalPrice += book.price
    romanPriceLength++
  }
}

console.log(TotalPrice / romanPriceLength)
console.log((TotalPrice / romanPriceLength).toFixed(0))
```

Comment: You forgot to check if `type` is `roman`, case-insensitively.

Comment: Oh wait yeah I forgot

Comment: You have to divide by the number of roman books, not the length of the array.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `filter` and `reduce` too :

```js
let books = [
    { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
    { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
    { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
    { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hoho', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
]

const romans = books.filter(book => book.type.toLowerCase() == 'roman') 
const romansTotalPrice = romans.reduce((a, {price}) => a + price, 0)
const romansAvaragePrice = (romansTotalPrice / romans.length).toFixed(2);
console.log(romansAvaragePrice)
```

Comment: You can avoid repeating `const` as well.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Hey mate :) sure I can , thanks, I just thought that it will be clearer this way, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop or `forEach()` to get the sum of prices and the count.

```js
let books = [
    { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
    { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
    { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
    { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hoho', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
]

let TotalPrice = 0;
let count = 0;

books.forEach(book => {
  if (book.type.toLowerCase() == 'roman') {
    TotalPrice += book.price;
    count++;
  }
});

console.log((TotalPrice / books.length).toFixed(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar suggested, you can use a simple [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop as well:

```js
let books = [{
    name: 'Some-1',
    author: 'Puskin',
    type: 'roman',
    price: 204.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Some-2',
    author: 'Tolstoy',
    type: 'ROMAN',
    price: 321.0
  },
  {
    name: 'Some-3',
    author: 'Pero',
    type: 'tale',
    price: 211.0
  },
  {
    name: 'Some-4',
    author: 'Koelyo',
    type: 'roman',
    price: 204.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Some-5',
    author: 'Christie',
    type: 'Roman',
    price: 245.5
  },
  {
    name: 'Some-6',
    author: 'Hoho',
    type: 'tale',
    price: 366.0
  }
];

var total = 0,
  romans = books.filter(book => book.type.toLowerCase() === 'roman');
for (var roman of romans) total += roman.price;
var average = (total / romans.length).toFixed(2);

console.log(average);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is already a little too late, here is my answer.My solution puts the types together and gives you an object with the average prices, counts and sum.

```js
books = [
    { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
    { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
    { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
    { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
    { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hohol', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
];

// find categories
index = books.map(item => item.type.toLowerCase() ).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)

// init category object with parameters: sum, count, average
const obj = {}
index.forEach(i => {
  obj[i] = {sum: 0, count: 0, average: 0}
});

// iterate bookObject and calculate values
books.forEach(book => {
  const sum = obj[book.type.toLowerCase()].sum + book.price
  const count = obj[book.type.toLowerCase()].count + 1  
  const average = sum / count
  
  obj[book.type.toLowerCase()].sum = sum
  obj[book.type.toLowerCase()].count = count
  obj[book.type.toLowerCase()].average = average
});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the average of items by type, you first need to filter the original list. Once you have filtered the list, you can then use a reducer function to sum the prices and divide by the length of the filtered list.

```js
const books = [
  { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
  { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
  { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
  { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
  { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
  { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hohol', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
];

// Round a number to a precision. Default 2 decimal places.
const round = (n, p = 2) => (e => Math.round(n * e) / e)(Math.pow(10, p));

// This is a "generic" average calculation
const calcAvg = (dataList, producer, predicate) =>
  (filtered =>
    filtered.reduce((sum, item) => sum + producer(item), 0) / filtered.length)
  (predicate ? dataList.filter(predicate) : dataList);

// Computed average of books with type="roman" (case-insensitive)
const avg = calcAvg(
  books, // list of items to filter on and compute average
  ({ price }) => price, // producer or data accessor
  ({ type }) => type.toLowerCase() === 'roman', // predicate or filter callback
); // 243.875

// Currency formatter
const cf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });

// Average price; rounded up to nearest cent
console.log(cf.format(round(avg))); // $243.88
```

Here is a code golf version:

```js
const books = [
  { name: 'Some-1', author: 'Puskin', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
  { name: 'Some-2', author: 'Tolstoy', type: 'ROMAN', price: 321.0 },
  { name: 'Some-3', author: 'Pero', type: 'tale', price: 211.0 },
  { name: 'Some-4', author: 'Koelyo', type: 'roman', price: 204.5 },
  { name: 'Some-5', author: 'Christie', type: 'Roman', price: 245.5 },
  { name: 'Some-6', author: 'Hohol', type: 'tale', price: 366.0 }
]

// 158 bytes
r=(n,p=2)=>(e=>((n*e)+.5|0)/e)(10**p);g=(l,a,p)=>(m=>m.reduce((s,i)=>s+a(i),0)/m.length)(p?l.filter(p):l);f=(l,t)=>g(l,o=>o.price,o=>o.type.toLowerCase()===t)

console.log(`$${r(f(books, 'roman'))}`) // $243.88
```